# how to skip UpdateTimestamp at the time of initial insertions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi have the below two date Column, when the data gets inserted very first time i need to have in Oracle

```
CREA_TS                      UPDT_TS  
2023-05-03 10:16:46.01653     null
```

but when updating(modify occurs), the column has to get updated automatically using `@UpdateTimestamp` annotation in Spring JPA

```
CREA_TS                      UPDT_TS  
2023-05-03 10:16:46.01653     2023-06-03 10:16:46.01653
```

the entity:

```
    @Column(name = "CREA_TS")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdGmts;

    @Column(name = "UPDT_TS")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedGmts;
```

does it worked with (insertable/updateable) or do we have any other best options

```
@Column(name = "CREA_TS", updatable=false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp createdDate;

@Column(name = "UPDT_TS", insertable=false)
@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp modifiedDate;
```